# How do I set CurrentMessageContext.TimeSent for testing in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus

I'm testing an NServiceBus saga that sends a command.  The command has an attribute that tracks the time an action was performed.  The handler for the message assigns `CurrentMessageContext.TimeSent` to `LastSentOn` in the outgoing message.

When I try to test the outgoing message, `LastSentOn` always has the value `DateTime.MinValue`, so....

How do I set CurrentMessageContext.TimeSent for testing in NServiceBus?

Comment: Quick guess, I think that is set in the message headers.  Have you tried modifying it there?

Answer (score 1):

Josh - this is not a direct answer to your question, but have you seen this?

http://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/808

Looks like CurrentMessageContext.TimeSent has been deprecated and is now just a setting in the message headers. Perhaps you can use the header value instead.